# Junit test case for database insert method with DAO and web service

Tags: java, web-services, junit, dao, testcase

I am implementing a webservice based university management system. This system adds certain courses to database. here below is the code that I am using.

**Course.java**

```
public class Course {

    private String courseName;
    private String location;
    private String courseId;


       public String getCourseId()
               {
        return courseId;
            }

    public void setCourseId(String courseId) {
        this.courseId = courseId;
    }

    public String getCourseName() {
        return courseName;
    }

    public void setCourseName(String courseName) {
        this.courseName = courseName;
    }

        public String getLocation() {
        return location;
    }
    public void setLocation(String location) {
        this.location = location;
    }
}
```

then another file is as below

**CourseDaoImpl.java**

```
public class CourseDaoImpl implements IDao {
   Connection conn = null;
   Statement stmt = null;

public CourseDaoImpl(){

try {
    Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
    conn = DriverManager.getConnection(
            "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/univesitydb", "root", "root");
    stmt = conn.createStatement();

    if (!conn.isClosed())
        System.out.println("Successfully connectiod");
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (InstantiationException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}

      @Override
  public String add(Object object) {

Course c = (Course) object ;

String courseId = c.getCourseId();
String courseName = c.getCourseName();
String location = c.getLocation();

String result = "";
int rowcount;

try {
    String query = "Insert into course (courseId,courseName,location) values"
            + " ('"
            + courseId
            + "', '"
            + courseName
            + "', '"
            + location
            + "')";
    rowcount = stmt.executeUpdate(query);
    if (rowcount > 0) {
        result = "true";
        System.out.println("Course inserted successful");
    } else {
        result = "false:The data could not be inserted in the databse";
    }
} catch (SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

return result;
}
```

the third is the Web service file as follows which interacts with the previous two and adds data to database.

**CourseService.java**

```
package edu.service;

          import edu.dao.IDao;
          import edu.dao.impl.CourseDaoImpl;
          import edu.db.entity.Course;

       public class CourseService {

     public String addCourse(String courseId, String courseName, String location)
    {   
       Course c = new Course();
       c.setCourseId(courseId);
       c.setCourseName(courseName);
       c.setLocation(location);     
       IDao dao = new CourseDaoImpl();
       return dao.add(c);   
     }
```

Looking at my code listings can any body suggest me how do I write test case for my add method. I am totally beginner for JAVA, I took help from my friends to learn this java part and Now need to implement Junit test for my database methods like add course above.

Please suggest some thing that I can learn , read and use to implement Junit testing for my database methods.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is one sample dao test using junit in spring project.

```
import java.util.List;

import junit.framework.Assert;

import org.jboss.tools.example.springmvc.domain.Member;
import org.jboss.tools.example.springmvc.repo.MemberDao;
import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.test.context.ContextConfiguration;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner;
import org.springframework.test.context.transaction.TransactionConfiguration;
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional;

@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations={"classpath:test-context.xml",
"classpath:/META-INF/spring/applicationContext.xml"})
@Transactional
@TransactionConfiguration(defaultRollback=true)
public class MemberDaoTest
{
    @Autowired
    private MemberDao memberDao;

    @Test
    public void testFindById()
    {
        Member member = memberDao.findById(0l);

        Assert.assertEquals("John Smith", member.getName());
        Assert.assertEquals("john.smith@mailinator.com", member.getEmail());
        Assert.assertEquals("2125551212", member.getPhoneNumber());
        return;
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindByEmail()
    {
        Member member = memberDao.findByEmail("john.smith@mailinator.com");

        Assert.assertEquals("John Smith", member.getName());
        Assert.assertEquals("john.smith@mailinator.com", member.getEmail());
        Assert.assertEquals("2125551212", member.getPhoneNumber());
        return;
    }

    @Test
    public void testRegister()
    {
        Member member = new Member();
        member.setEmail("jane.doe@mailinator.com");
        member.setName("Jane Doe");
        member.setPhoneNumber("2125552121");

        memberDao.register(member);
        Long id = member.getId();
        Assert.assertNotNull(id);

        Assert.assertEquals(2, memberDao.findAllOrderedByName().size());
        Member newMember = memberDao.findById(id);

        Assert.assertEquals("Jane Doe", newMember.getName());
        Assert.assertEquals("jane.doe@mailinator.com", newMember.getEmail());
        Assert.assertEquals("2125552121", newMember.getPhoneNumber());
        return;
    }

    @Test
    public void testFindAllOrderedByName()
    {
        Member member = new Member();
        member.setEmail("jane.doe@mailinator.com");
        member.setName("Jane Doe");
        member.setPhoneNumber("2125552121");
        memberDao.register(member);

        List<Member> members = memberDao.findAllOrderedByName();
        Assert.assertEquals(2, members.size());
        Member newMember = members.get(0);

        Assert.assertEquals("Jane Doe", newMember.getName());
        Assert.assertEquals("jane.doe@mailinator.com", newMember.getEmail());
        Assert.assertEquals("2125552121", newMember.getPhoneNumber());
        return;
    }
}
```

Comment: In the test method `testRegister()` you are using the DAO method `Member newMember = memberDao.findById(id)`, after performing `memberDao.register(member)`

Is this the right way to do it? I think you must try and fetch the database values and assert those values. Because any bugs from `memberDao.findById(id)` may have side effects on your `testRegister()` method.

Comment: @HariKrishnaGanji I think that is right. By using `findById(id)`, after calling `register`, you're actually testing `findById` and not `register`. And this could affect when `register` fails to input some values(buggy) and `findById` returns some default values(buggy), and hence might not be caught.

Comment: can anyone please explain - what is "classpath:test-context.xml" entry and what should be in that file?

Comment: I have a small doubt. In this scenario When we build the project eachtime the value get inserted to all the tables of the database. (Considering all insert method have test cases.) There may be more then one test cases and each build will insert values to database. I don't think this will be a good.(In production environment)

Comment: @Crocode, Just a thought. First run the testcase for testFindById() if it is successful then only we have to run tests for testRegister(). Can we do like this? Anyway if it fails to fetch the data using testFindById(), the build will not be successful.

Answer (score 5):

The design of your classes will make it hard to test them. Using hardcoded connection strings or instantiating collaborators in your methods with `new` can be considered as test-antipatterns. Have a look at the [DependencyInjection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection) pattern. Frameworks like [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) might be of help here.

To have your DAO tested you need to have control over your database connection in your unit tests. So the first thing you would want to do is extract it out of your DAO into a class that you can either mock or point to a specific test database, which you can setup and inspect before and after your tests run.

A technical solution for testing db/DAO code might be [dbunit](http://www.dbunit.org/). You can define your test data in a schema-less XML and let dbunit populate it in your test database. But you still have to wire everything up yourself. With Spring however you could use something like [spring-test-dbunit](http://springtestdbunit.github.io/spring-test-dbunit/) which gives you lots of leverage and additional tooling.

As you call yourself a total beginner I suspect this is all very daunting. You should ask yourself if you really need to test your database code. If not you should at least refactor your code, so you can easily mock out all database access. For mocking in general, have a look at [Mockito](http://code.google.com/p/mockito/).

Comment: Thanks for the Help, Even I have never worked with Springs. I do not know much whether really I should test my code or not but my project partners need to do it and I was assigned the task of doing it. Any ways thanks for the help. I will look forward to it.

Answer (score 2):

```
@Test
public void testSearchManagementStaff() throws SQLException
{
    boolean res=true;
    ManagementDaoImp mdi=new ManagementDaoImp();
    boolean b=mdi.searchManagementStaff("abc@gmail.com"," 123456");
    assertEquals(res,b);
}
```

Answer (score -5):

/*

public class UserDAO {

```
public boolean insertUser(UserBean u) {
    boolean flag = false;
    MySqlConnection msq = new MySqlConnection();
    try {

        String sql = "insert into regis values(?,?,?,?,?)";

        Connection connection = msq.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        statement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1, u.getname());
        statement.setString(2, u.getlname());
        statement.setString(3, u.getemail());
        statement.setString(4, u.getusername());
        statement.setString(5, u.getpasswords());
        statement.executeUpdate();

        flag = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        return flag;
    }

}

public String userValidate(UserBean u) {
    String login = "";
    MySqlConnection msq = new MySqlConnection();
    try {
        String email = u.getemail();
        String Pass = u.getpasswords();

        String sql = "SELECT name FROM regis WHERE email=? and passwords=?";
        com.mysql.jdbc.Connection connection = msq.getConnection();
        com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement statement = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;
        statement = (com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1, email);
        statement.setString(2, Pass);
        rs = statement.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            login = rs.getString("name");
        } else {
            login = "false";
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        return login;
    }
}

public boolean getmessage(UserBean u) {
    boolean flag = false;
    MySqlConnection msq = new MySqlConnection();
    try {


        String sql = "insert into feedback values(?,?)";

        Connection connection = msq.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        statement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1, u.getemail());
        statement.setString(2, u.getfeedback());
        statement.executeUpdate();

        flag = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
    } finally {
        return flag;
    }

}

public boolean insertOrder(cartbean u) {
    boolean flag = false;
    MySqlConnection msq = new MySqlConnection();
    try {

        String sql = "insert into cart (product_id, email, Tprice, quantity) values (?,?,2000,?)";

        Connection connection = msq.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement statement = null;
        statement = (PreparedStatement) connection.prepareStatement(sql);
        statement.setString(1, u.getpid());
        statement.setString(2, u.getemail());
        statement.setString(3, u.getquantity());

        statement.executeUpdate();

        flag = true;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.print("hi");
    } finally {
        return flag;
    }

}
```

}