# Doesn't receive an error in java test

Tags: java, testing, junit, mocking, mockito

My test shouldn't pass. I should receive an error at row #2, because I put a wrong value `new Long(0)` at row #1. 
Please tell me where is my mistake.
Thanks.

```
    @Test
    public void getPersonListByOtdelIdTest() {            
        Long otdelId = new Long(454);
        ArgumentCaptor<Long> argumentOtdelId = ArgumentCaptor.forClass(Long.class);
        SessionFactory mockedSessionFactory = mock(SessionFactory.class);
        Session session = mock(Session.class);
        Query query = mock(Query.class);
        PersonDAOImpl personDAO = new PersonDAOImpl(mockedSessionFactory);
        when(mockedSessionFactory.getCurrentSession()). thenReturn(session);
        when(session.createQuery("FROM Person P where P.otdel.otdelId = :otdelId")).thenReturn(query);
 #1-->  when(query.setParameter("otdelId", new Long(0))).thenReturn(query);
        when(query.list()).thenReturn(persons);

        List<Person> expectedPersons =  personDAO.getPersonListByOtdelId(otdelId);

        verify(mockedSessionFactory).getCurrentSession();
        verify(session).createQuery("FROM Person P where P.otdel.otdelId = :otdelId");
        verify(query).setParameter(eq("otdelId"), argumentOtdelId.capture());
        verify(query).list();
 #2-->  assertEquals(otdelId, argumentOtdelId.getValue());
        assertTrue(expectedPersons.containsAll(persons));
    }

 public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO {
    public List<Person> getPersonListByOtdelId(Long otdelId) {
        Query query = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createQuery("FROM Person P where P.otdel.otdelId = :otdelId");
        query.setParameter("otdelId", otdelId);
        List<Person> listPersons = query.list();
        return listPersons;
    } 
 }
```

Comment: What kind of mocking API you are working on ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see why you would expect an assertion failure at #2. Your test passed in `454` (as a `Long`) into `getPersonListByOtdelId()`, so that will be passed to `query.setParameter()`. The `when()` code in #1 is essentially a no-op, because there is no call to `query.setParameter()` with those values, but Mockito won't complain if the call specified in a `when()` never happens, and the code under test doesn't check the return value, so there's no exception.

In any case, you don't need an `ArgumentCaptor`; you just need to have Mockito verify that the correct value was passed to `setParameter()`

In fact, many of verify calls aren't needed you could just do this:

```
@Test
public void getPersonListByOtdelIdTest() {
  Long otdelId = 454L; // or = Long.valueOf(454); don't use new Long
  SessionFactory mockedSessionFactory = mock(SessionFactory.class);
  Session session = mock(Session.class);
  Query query = mock(Query.class);

  when(mockedSessionFactory.getCurrentSession()).thenReturn(session);
  when(session.createQuery("FROM Person P where P.otdel.otdelId = :otdelId"))
      .thenReturn(query);
  when(query.setParameter("otdelId", otdelId)).thenReturn(query);
  when(query.list()).thenReturn(persons);

  PersonDAOImpl personDAO = new PersonDAOImpl(mockedSessionFactory);
  List<Person> result = personDAO.getPersonListByOtdelId(otdelId);

  verify(query).setParameter("otdelId", otdelId);
  assertEquals(result, persons);
}
```

You don't need to verify that `getCurrentSession()` is called, because if it wasn't the code under test wouldn't get a session. You don't need to verify that the correct query was passed to `createQuery()`, because of the code under test used a different query, Mockito wouldn't return a mock query (unless, of course, you use [RETURNS_MOCKS](http://docs.mockito.googlecode.com/hg/org/mockito/Mockito.html#RETURNS_MOCKS)).

That all being said, **I don't think the above test is a good test**. The test is almost exactly mirroring the code, and it doesn't verify that the code will work. In other words, it's a [change detector test](http://googletesting.blogspot.com/2015/01/testing-on-toilet-change-detector-tests.html).

I wouldn't use a mocking framework to test `PersonDaoImpl`. Instead, I would write a test that started an in-memory database, using a schema file that is also used to create the actual table in production.

I would use a mock for tests for a class that depends on `PersonDAO`.

Comment: mocking framework is not fit for DAO classes so what we should do when we have to write unit test for the classes ?

Comment: @TienNguyen as I said, if I was writing tests tests for a DAO class, I would have the test create an in-memory database, and have the DAO interact with the database created by the test. That's the minimal thing that would give me confidence that the DAO class worked. In the example test above, if the name of the column was `odtelId`, but the code and the tests used `otdelId`, then the test would pass, but the class would throw exceptions in production.

Comment: @NamshubWriter Thank you very much for your detailed explanation. As I understand I should use mocking tests at the service and controller levels. Is it a good example of dao level testing: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16261838/junit-test-case-for-database-insert-method-with-dao-and-web-service)?

Comment: @zigfridus the [accepted answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17440820/95725]) to that question looks like a good DAO test to me. I would add a `@Before` method that inserted some example data using raw SQL.

Comment: ok, thank you again. I'll change my dao tests according your advice.